# Aurelia Error: Potentially unhandled rejection [4] Unexpected token @

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs, aurelia, ecmascript-2016

So, the docs for Aurelia were recently updated and now a lot of things were replaced with decorators, like `@binding`. When I try to use them, I get the error:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [4] Unexpected token @ (WARNING:
>   non-Error used)

I've run all forms of npm update but I still get the error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that even though I kept running `npm update`, my config was instructing npm to fetch a 4.0.0 version of babel. [Decorators were included in the babel 5.0.0 release](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/). Therefore, I needed to make the following edit to my `package.json` file:

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-babel": "^5.0.0",
  }
}
```

Then, I ran `npm update gulp-babel`, npm fetched the correct packages, and everything worked correctly.